# Creating A Bootable Drive For Ubuntu on Mac

Tags: usb-drive, macosx

I've decided to switch from OS X to Ubuntu. I'm following this [documentation](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx) on Ubuntu's site for creating a bootable USB Drive.

1. I created the ISO to IMG.
2. I ran `diskutil list` and inserted my flash drive and ran `diskutil list` again. My drive is assigned to `/dev/disk1`.
3. I ran `diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk1`, then executed `sudo dd if=/ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.dmg of=/dev/rdisk1 bs=1m`
4. Then I ran `diskutil eject /dev/disk1`. Then I restarted, held the <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>option key</kbd>.
   The Boot Manager came up, **but my flash drive wasn't coming up as an option**.

I tried this again just now and it said:

> ```
> The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer.
> ```

I've never had an issue with this drive before. I restarted anyway, just to see if it worked and I'm still only getting my main hard drive as an option in Boot Manager.

Where do I go from here?

Comment: This looks promising: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/

Comment: I spotted an error: The option-key is the alt-key (in os x), which brings up the `startup manager`, before the system is booted. (Maybe edit your Q and correct that). Not sure now, if this is the reason it is not shown as a possible boot option?!

Comment: That link didn't work, as it was for Linux and Windows, not Mac OS X.

Comment: I didn't put that there, someone else edited my question and put that there. I put alt/opt.

Answer (score 0):

http://u.tpps.cf/7 
and
http://u.tpps.cf/8

These should do the trick.

Comment: Neither of those sites or coming up. It says that the pages can't be loaded.

Comment: I haven't had any problems with them, maybe try again today?

Comment: They still aren't coming up.

Comment: http://penguintosh.com/2012/02/26/linux-usb-creator-released/ ------http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm not at home right now, but I'll try this when I'm at my desktop and let you know if it worked. If it works, I'll be posting it on my blog and hope you don't mind me mentioning you. :)

Comment: I downloaded the Linux USB Creator twice and both times I received an error saying that the file was damaged and that I should move it to the Trash.

Comment: I downloaded Mac Linux USB Loader from SourceForge. It appears to have worked. I get a boot menu that I can either boot the Linux Kernel from the ISO, or change advanced booting options. I chose to boot the Linux Kernel from the ISO. I received an error saying Alloc and a long number, but my computer restarted itself before I could write the number down. Any suggestions?

Comment: I want to get Ubuntu installed so bad. I believe that all of this handwork will be worth it.